# Find points where $f(z)$ is holomophic and compute $f'(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, holomorphic-functions

If we have a complex function

$f(x+iy) = \cos(x)\cos(y)-i\sin(x)\sin(y)$ for $x,y ∈ {\rm I\!R}$

Find the set of points at which f:$\mathbb{C}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\mathbb{C}$ are holomorphic and compute $f '(z)$.

I understand how to differentiate the function however i'm unsure as to go about proving at which points the function is holomorphic. And how to show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holomorphic functions $f:\Omega\to \mathbb{C}$ satisfy a pair of partial differential equations called the Cauchy-Riemann Equations. If we write $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ then the Cauchy-Riemann Equations read
$$ \begin{cases}
u_x=v_y\\
u_y=-v_x.
\end{cases}$$
Compute the set of $(x,y)\in \mathbb{C}$ so  that $f$ satisfies these equations. Then, to differentiate, observe that 
$$ f'(z)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}.$$
However, because $h$ can tend to $0$ from whichever direction we wish, $f'(z)=u_x+iv_x$. In particular, the complex derivative is equal to either of the $x$ or $y$ partial derivatives.

Comment: yeah this makes a lot of sense I've figured out the Cauchy-Reimann equations and found that 
cos(x)sin(y)=-cos(x)sin(y) which can't be true so since they don't satisfy the Cauchy Reimann equations the function isn't holomorphic for any values of x,y